# merging 2 multidimensional arrays at the same index

Tags: javascript

javascript

I'm trying to either merge 2 multidimensional arrays at the same index or randomize the same index of both arrays the same.

```
var arr1 = [[a, b, c], [d, e], [f, g, h, i]]
var arr2 = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

preferredResult = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {d: 5, e:6}, {f: 7, g: 8, h: 9, i: 10}]
```

I've tried .maps, nested for loops, .push in different variations and have not been able to figure this out.

Alternatively, if I could figure out how randomize two arrays of arrays in the same way, that would work as well, ie: the letters in arr1[0] and numbers in arr2[0] could be set to the same randomization, then arr1[1] & arr2[1] and so on.

Comment: your prefered result should be `[ {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {d: 5, e:6}, {f: 7, g: 8, h: 9, i: 10}]`. the inner elements should be objects, not arrays.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you.

Comment: simplest way to process a two dimensional list is with a nested loop.  the outer loop iterates over each item in the top level array, the inner loop iterates over each item in the second level array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function merge(arr1, arr2) {
   return arr1.map(function (arr, i) {
      return mergeIntoObject(arr1[i], arr2[i])); 
   };
}

function mergeIntoObject(arr1, arr2) {
  var result = {};
  arr1.forEach((arr, i) => {
    result[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
  });
  return result;
}

merge(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using embedded `for` loops

```js
var arr1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']]
var arr2 = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

var result = []
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    let obj = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++){
        obj[arr1[i][j]]=arr2[i][j]
    }
    result.push(obj);
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It is creating object for each of the element from arr1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` and `array#reduce`

```js
const arr1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d','e' ], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']],
      arr2 = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]],
      result = arr1.map(function(a, i){
        return a.reduce(function(r, v, j){
          r[v] = arr2[i][j];
          return r;
        }, {});
      });
      
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash can be super helpful.

```js
var arr1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']]
var arr2 = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]

var out = _.zipWith(arr1, arr2, (x,y)=>_.fromPairs(_.zip(x,y)));
console.log(out)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

zip will combine 2 arrays into pairs and zipWith will do the same but let you choose how to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` & `forEach` method

```js
var arr1 = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e'],
    ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
  ],
  arr2 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 10]
  ],
  m = arr1.map(function(item, index) {
    let tempObj = {};
    item.forEach(function(item2, index2) {
      tempObj[item2] = arr2[index][index2];
    });
    return tempObj;
  });
console.log(m)
```